# Submitting a form with a javascript target using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms

## Background

I have a HTML form that I am trying to submit using the Python **Requests** module.

This is the HTML for the form:

```
<form name="main" id="main" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
```

---

## Javascript files involved

The **validateForm()** function looks like this:

```
      function validateForm(form)
      {
        if (form.buttonClicked[0].value == "delete"){
          deleteCount += 1;

          if (deleteCount > 1){

           return false;
          }
          if(form.allowValidateOnDelete && form.allowValidateOnDelete.value == "true")
          {
            deleteCount = 0;
            return validate(form);
          }
          else
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
        else{
          return validate(form);
        }
      }
```

---

This is **validate()**

```
function trimAll(form)
{
  form.forwardedToNumber.value = trim(form.forwardedToNumber.value);
}

function validate(form)
{
    trimAll(form);

    for (var i=0; i < form.active.length; i++) {
      if (form.active[i].checked) {
        if (form.active[i].value == "false") {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (form.forwardedToNumber.value == "") {
        alert(errorText(1000, errorText(2201)));
        form.forwardedToNumber.select();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

## Question

How do I submit this form using Python?

I can't really submit the below example because it doesn't make sense as a URI:

```
session.request(
    'POST', 
    'https://example.com/return validateForm(this);', 
    data={'active': 'true'}
)
```

How I would go about submitting a form which has a target of `return function();` ?

Comment: The form endpoint will probably be `'https://example.com/'` and not `'https://example.com/return validateForm(this);'` judging from the code. Since there is no target, it will probably be `/`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSubmit` handler should not be confused with the `action` of the form (i.e. the URL that the data will be posted to). You should see the `onSubmit` as a trigger that is activated as soon as the user submits the form. If the return value of the handler is false, the form data will not be sent to the server at all.

To do the same using `requests`, you need to determine what the form's `action` attribute is. If the form has no `action` attribute, it will post the data to the same URL as where it got the form in the first place.

Comment: You are right. When I submit it at the same page, it does submit the form and return to the page. I'm now getting an OCI XML error and something about xsi:nil attributes, but that's a different issue.